# Label not showing up in overlay UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Ok, I have done this kind of thing a million times but this particular case escapes me and I'm sure its just something stupid I am missing...

But I am trying to display a UIView on top of a mapView to give the impression the mapview is 'disabled.'

I created a UIView subclass and added a single label. like so...

.h

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface DisabledOverlayView : UIView

  @property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *disabledOverlayViewText;

  @end
```

nothing complicated...

in my .m I set the text and add it to my UIView.

```
@synthesize disabledOverlayViewText = _disabledOverlayViewText;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
 self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.alpha = 1;

    _disabledOverlayViewText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _disabledOverlayViewText.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    // [_disabledOverlayViewText setCenter:self.center];
    _disabledOverlayViewText.text = @"testing";
    [self addSubview:_disabledOverlayViewText];
}
return self;
```

}

then the class i wish to use this overlay i call it with...

```
    DisabledOverlayView *disabledView = [[DisabledOverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 12, _mapView.frame.size.width, _mapView.frame.size.height)];
    disabledView.disabledOverlayViewText.text = @"No Location";
    [self.view addSubview:disabledView];
```

None of this is too complicated.. but the label doesn't show up.  the overlay appears just fine, but no label text.  Ive messed with the frames of the label thinking maybe it was off the visible view but no dice. and i cannot figure out what is going on.

Comment: you know that your DisabledOverlayView.textView frame will always be the same? and do you add your label after you added your mapview as subview?

Comment: Yes, the label's frame will always be the same, because Ive hardcoded it.  And the label should be added on the init call of my DisabledOverlayView.  The mapView already exists (its in a xib) and I run a data check to see if it should be disabled or not, then create my overlay (which would then in turn create the label).  So yes, the label should be created after the mapview is allocated.  Either way though, the label is unrelated to the map.  entirely.

Comment: You're not creating  _disabledOverlayViewText. This init is for the overlay view itself, right? Where's the alloc init for the label?

Comment: I agree, where is the init for the label?

Comment: try printing frame of label, afler you add that..

Comment: i am, or should be, allocating the label inside the init of the DisabledOverlayView class

Comment: label is in UI and connected via outlet as per i think

Comment: Ah right, i see.   Yes I was missing the alloc init line.  I could of sworn it was there.  That was the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `initWithFrame` method with the below code. I have added the alloc init line and changes the background color of the `label`. Try it and see whether it works :)

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.alpha = 1;

       _disabledOverlayViewText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
       _disabledOverlayViewText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       _disabledOverlayViewText.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        // [_disabledOverlayViewText setCenter:self.center];
       _disabledOverlayViewText.text = @"testing";
       [self.view addSubview:_disabledOverlayViewText];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the label is not allocated and it's nil.

Try this

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
  {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {

  self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  self.alpha = 1;

  **self.disabledOverlayViewText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];**

  _disabledOverlayViewText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  // [_disabledOverlayViewText setCenter:self.center];

  _disabledOverlayViewText.text = @"testing";

  [self addSubview:_disabledOverlayViewText];
  }